# typescript The types do not match in array processing

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I use typescript and react.
Loop through ISerch's sampleQuery, dammyQuery, foodQuery, and groupQuery with items.
I get the following error at save[i].query.

tsError

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ISearch'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ISearch'.
```

```
interface ISearch {
  test: string；
  sampleQuery: { id: number; query: string };
  dammyQuery: { id: number; query: string };
  foodQuery: { id: number; query: string };
  groupQuery: { id: number; query: string };
}

const searchText = (save: ISearch) => {
  const items = ['sampleQuery', 'dammyQuery', 'foodQuery', 'groupQuery'];

  let text = '';

  items.map((i) => {
    if (save[i].query != '') {
      text = text.concat(save[i].query + ',');
    }
  });
  return text;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm think there's a more elegant way to do this, but here's my solution:

```
items.map((i) => {
    let key = i as keyof ISearch
    if (save[key].query != '') {
      text = text.concat(save[key].query + ',');
    }
});
```

Here's a working playgroud example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUJyggFsgbwFgAoZZAZzgFsAHAGwgEUBXaATwC5DlgATbiBbUARtADcyAI5soXSmCigA5sgC+40uT41q7Vh24FeA5ENETps+RUUr1msshgB7F3wNyjJwcLFRJGUMFJRBVDS1kZSgXFlpPeWN+XwsAq2DbUPDHNVJSBBcQW0o4ADcIbgwsHHwAXkJIqjpGBO9k5AAGABp0r2QAciaGZmt+9S7InWo9Vp52gEYeoL7+qZnR8cjXd1mk0wAmJetufu2PDbUJp2jY+OO50wBmI+D+m7iEsdySb7ySfMKxWAkGoFGQ9QA2oMaMNPj1Vrp9KN4Wc4QN3ncOP0ALqOUiMMDISAAD0J9X6-TxJGBEFBADpqHBaAAKZnAbiZFQASnBAD4Gk4CcgANYQdjg3jIOBg0XsFwwNCYbB4RzkYAK5lUcoQ2XYunLcUAQnJ-R5xCc5BJZKJEFJdIKIAQcDAmrKEB1Yr1BuQAGoBl1Tar1KQ1FyqQ6KC5GHT6C5lMyrWHSEA

Comment: What error did you get? "In the query" is not very descriptive :)

Comment: I was not able to Save. It worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

just

```
const items = ['sampleQuery', 'dammyQuery', 'foodQuery', 'groupQuery'] as const;
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```js
type TItemKey = 'sampleQuery' | 'dammyQuery' | 'foodQuery' | 'groupQuery';
type TSearch = {
  [key in TItemKey]: { id: number; query: string };
} & { test: string }

const searchText = (save: TSearch) => {
  const items: TItemKey[] = ['sampleQuery', 'dammyQuery', 'foodQuery', 'groupQuery'];

  let text = '';

  items.map((i) => {
    if (save[i].query != '') {
      text = text.concat(save[i].query + ',');
    }
  });
  return text;
};
```